# jQuery splitbutton

Tags: jquery-ui-plugins

Has anyone taken the jQuery split-button buttonset() functionality to make a ready-to-use SplitButton plug-in with the dropdown-menu functionality already built-in, and which is also theme-savvy?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this tutorial: http://jquery-easyui.wikidot.com/tutorial:splitbutton. It may help you.